# Elasticsearch field name aliasing

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is it possible to setup alias for field names in elasticsearch? (Just like how index names can be aliased)

For example: i have a document {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'smith'}

I would like to alias 'firstname' to 'fn'...

Answer (score 10):

Just a quick update, Elasticsearch `6.4` came up with feature called **[Alias Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/alias.html)**. Check the below mapping and query as sample.

Note that the type of the field is `alias` in the below mapping for fieldname `fn`

### Sample Mapping:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "firstname": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "fn": {
          "type": "alias",
          "path": "firstname" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Query:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "fn" : "Steve"
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to use the `alias` for actual field on which inverted index is created. Note that fields with alias datatype aren't meant for `write` operations and its only meant for querying purpose.

Although you can refer to the link I've mentioned for more details, below are just some of the important points.

- Field alias is only meant to be used when your index has a `single mapping`. Index has to be created post `6.xx` version or be created in older version with the setting `index.mapping.single_type: true`
- Can be used in `querying`, `aggregations`, `sorting`, `highlighting` and `suggestion` operations
- Target field must be actual field on which inverted index is created
- Cannot create `alias` of another `alias` field
- Cannot use `alias` on multiple fields. Single alias, Single field.
- **Cannot be used** as part of source filtering using `_source`.

Comment: "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
            "reason": "index [sync_refund/XQhtEh6CR-Ogw4XiWQXLCQ] already exists",
            "index_uuid": "XQhtEh6CR-Ogw4XiWQXLCQ",
            "index": "sync_refund"
          }
        ]


i've got this error message, version 6.8

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct field alias functionality. However, you could rename the fields upon indexing using the index_name property in your mappings.

> index_name : The name of the field that will be stored in the index.
>   Defaults to the property/field name.

See here for more information: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

Comment: I tried index_name in the mapping. "Keeeeeey1" : { "type" : "string", "index_name": "k1" }. I inserted few documents and when I lookup  http://localhost:9200/testalias/_search?q=*&pretty I get the results with document field name "Keeeeeey1". I am assuming this is correct because, "k1" is just stored internally within the store and all displays will show "Keeeeeey1". Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: FYI...My reason to use alias is to reduce the db size....by reducing the size of longer key names to shorter alias name

Comment: Actually the index keeps the "k1" as default field name. However, since the docs stored in elasticsearch are schemaless you can of course post a new doc {"Keeeeey1":"value1"}. Elasticsearch is clever enough to understand that when querying on k1 field, docs that have been indexed like I mentioned before should be included. When querying or using a field name there is an automatic detection from logical full path and into the index_name and vice versa. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html for more info.

Comment: The link no longer works: does anyone know where this information can be found these days?

Answer (score 1):

Adding alias `fn` for existing field `firstname`

```
PUT myindex/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "fn": {
      "type": "alias",
      "path": "firstname" 
    }
  }
}
```

Should work this way as of Elasticsearch 7.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try creating an alias on your index with filter on the desired field. Your filter must be written in such a way that it selects all the entries from your field. Please refer Filtered aliases section in [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html). But I am interested in knowing your use case. Why you want to create alias on particular field.

Comment: My reason to use alias is to reduce the db size....by reducing the size of longer key names to shorter alias name