# ElasticSearch: Fetching record with a alias for fieldname

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case where I have to store documents with field names after some processing. But for search purposes I want that document to return with an alias of mine.

This is specific to removing Dots "." from the input field names, but keeping the search results oblivious of the change.
Example:

```
Fieldname recieved: My.Field.Name
Processed name in ES: My<Separator>Field<Separator>Name
Expected Search Result: My.Field.Name
```

I am assuming that Field Aliases are not supported by ElasticSearch right now. But is there any work around for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497771/elasticsearch-field-name-aliasing?rq=1

Comment: This post has a different use case as far as I could understand. My use case is related to IllegalCharacters in the field names.