# Why can't I define an Alias datatype on an AWS Elasticsearch index property?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

In my dev environment, I can create an Elasticsearch index having a **property** with an **Alias datatype**. However, in AWS (Elasticsearch Service) when I attempt the same operation, it fails.

My dev Elasticsearch version: 6.4.2
AWS Elasticsearch version: 6.3.1

I'm trying it with sample code from the Elasticsearch site: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/alias.html

```
PUT trips
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "distance": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "route_length_miles": {
                    "type": "alias",
                    "path": "distance"
                },
                "transit_mode": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "No handler for type [alias] declared on field [route_length_miles]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No handler for type [alias] declared on field [route_length_miles]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "No handler for type [alias] declared on field [route_length_miles]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Alias datatype was introduced in version 6.4--a bit odd to add a datatype in a "minor" update.

The following links mention "field" aliases, but I assume this includes "property" aliases, as well:

[Elasticsearch field name aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497771/elasticsearch-field-name-aliasing)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/release-notes-6.4.0.html

I can either wait for AWS to upgrade Elasticsearch to version 6.4 or find a workaround.

Comment: Why is adding features in a minor version weird? That's pretty much textbook semver. And yeah, field aliases are set through the properties in the mapping, so that's the feature you are after and it was added in 6.4. If you need current versions you can use https://cloud.elastic.co from the makers of Elasticsearch — same day release as a download and on cloud.