# What's the queivalent way to mysql's select as in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, select, rename

How to rename the query response field name just like mysql's `select as` query in Elasticsearch?

**Note** this is on the query not influence the index process which is different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497771)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch field name aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497771/elasticsearch-field-name-aliasing)

Comment: I need to only do it in the query without modify the index.

Comment: There is no equivalent, you can't do that in elasticsearch. If you need it, you will need to do that in the application side.