# Grafana - display not only grouping by results, but also other corresponding values

Tags: grafana

I have elasticsearch datasource, with the documents having a few fields (let's say A, B, C, D).
In Grafana I want to create a table with max Bs grouping by A, but also display C and D corresponding with each max B value.

I tried using join by field transformation - joining the grouping by outcome with raw data from elasticsearch, but it didn't work, since in grouping by result the column with max B values is called "Max" and joining didn't work correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Grafana is not the best place to do such an aggregation: joins have rather severe limitations. But it might(!) be solvable with clever elastic query. I recommend you to [edit] this question, put your actual (or minimized reasonably) query in it and adding related elasticsearch tags.

Comment: And if you'll find out that it is impossible with elsatic (or want to join in Grafana for whatever other reason), you could try [aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497771).